# How to make a table and introduce data from another file in it? Also how could I move the whole table around?

Tags: python, tkinter

So my idea is that I have a button that creates a table and introduces data from vectors (or a list? that is located in another file) in each column.

Here is a code sample:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def x():
    rows = []
    for i in range(5):
        cols = []
        for j in range(4):
            e = Entry(relief=GROOVE)
            e.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky=NSEW)
            e.insert(END, '%d.%d' % (i, j))
            cols.append(e)
            rows.append(cols)
            
create_b = Button(text="Create the table", bd=4, relief="groove", command=x)
create_b.place(x=50,y=10)
root.mainloop()
```

How can I make it so the table doesn't delete the button and it just places the table below the button? Also how can I make it so i can move the whole table at once like the `.place(...)` does?

Comment: Why don't you put the table in a `tkinter.Frame`? That way you can move it around freely

Comment: @TheLizzard How can I do that? Like place the whole def x() in a frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the whole table in a frame, you can then move it around. I recommend subclassing `tk.Frame` so you can treat it like a normal widget.

Here's how I would do it: First, inherit from `Frame`. Then, construct the table by making all of the widgets use the frame (self) as their parent. Once you've done that, you can use the instance of the table pretty much like you can use any other widget.

In the following example, I'm using what I think is a better way to import tkinter than what you used in your example. Other than that, notice how `x` is able to use `CustomTable` as if it was a regular widget, and that you can pass in the number of rows and columns as arguments when creating the table.

```
import tkinter as tk

class CustomTable(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent,  rows=5, columns=5, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

        self.rows = []
        for i in range(rows):
            cols = []
            for j in range(columns):
                e = tk.Entry(self, relief=tk.GROOVE)
                e.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky=tk.NSEW)
                e.insert(tk.END, '%d.%d' % (i, j))
                cols.append(e)
            self.rows.append(cols)


def x():
    table = CustomTable(root, rows=4, columns=3, bd=1, relief="raised")
    table.place(x=50, y=50)

root = tk.Tk()
create_b = tk.Button(root, text="Create the table", bd=4, relief="groove", command=x)
create_b.place(x=50,y=10)
root.mainloop()
```

If you aren't familiar with object-oriented programming, you can get the same effect using a function, though I think the object-oriented approach leads to slightly cleaner code.

```
import tkinter as tk

def create_table(parent, nrows=5, ncolumns=5, **kwargs):
    global rows

    frame = tk.Frame(parent, **kwargs)
    rows = []
    for i in range(nrows):
        cols = []
        for j in range(ncolumns):
            e = tk.Entry(frame, relief=tk.GROOVE)
            e.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky=tk.NSEW)
            e.insert(tk.END, '%d.%d' % (i, j))
            cols.append(e)
        rows.append(cols)
    return frame

def x():
    table = create_table(root, bd=1, relief="raised")
    table.place(x=50, y=50)

root = tk.Tk()
create_b = tk.Button(root, text="Create the table", bd=4, relief="groove", command=x)
create_b.place(x=50,y=10)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't think OP is very familiar with OOP. Also wouldn't it be easier to just have `rows=5, columns=5` in `def __init__(self, parent,  **kwargs)`? That way you wouldn't need to pop the dictionary

Comment: Yes, you could use rows and columns as distinct keyword arguments. I'll edit the answer, which will make it a bit cleaner. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I think that `self.rows.append(cols)` should have 1 less indentation. Otherwise `self.rows` will look something like: `[[<Entry1>], <Entry1>, <Entry2>], [<Entry1>, <Entry2>, <Entry3>], ...]`. `<Entry1>` will be repeated `j` number of times and the list wouldn't be in a matrix format.

Comment: @TheLizzard: why did you make revision 6? It doesn't change the behavior of the code.

Comment: My bad, I forgot that lists are mutable. Sorry